# Angular2 Tutorial 404 node_module/systemjs/*.map

Tags: angularjs, node.js, npm, systemjs

I'm running the Angular2 TypeScript QuickStart (https://angular.io/guide/quickstart) on Ubuntu 16.04 and while it works otherwise fine, I'm getting some 404's for .map files when I run `npm start`:

```
npm start
[1] 16.10.27 14:52:45 304 GET /index.html
[1] 16.10.27 14:52:45 304 GET /styles.css
[1] 16.10.27 14:52:45 304 GET /node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js
[1] 16.10.27 14:52:45 304 GET /node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js
[1] 16.10.27 14:52:45 304 GET /node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js
[1] 16.10.27 14:52:45 304 GET /node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js
[1] 16.10.27 14:52:45 304 GET /systemjs.config.js
[1] 16.10.27 14:52:46 304 GET /app/main.js
[1] 16.10.27 14:52:47 304 GET /node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-    dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js
[1] 16.10.27 14:52:47 304 GET /app/app.module.js
[1] 16.10.27 14:52:47 304 GET /node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles    /compiler.umd.js
[1] 16.10.27 14:52:47 304 GET /node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js
[1] 16.10.27 14:52:47 304 GET /node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js
[1] 16.10.27 14:52:47 304 GET /app/app.component.js
[1] 16.10.27 14:52:47 304 GET /node_modules/rxjs/Subject.js
[1] 16.10.27 14:52:47 304 GET /node_modules/rxjs/Observable.js
[1] 16.10.27 14:52:47 304 GET /node_modules/@angular/common/bundles    /common.umd.js
[1] 16.10.27 14:52:48 304 GET /node_modules/rxjs/Subscriber.js
[1] 16.10.27 14:52:48 304 GET /node_modules/rxjs/Subscription.js
[1] 16.10.27 14:52:48 304 GET /node_modules/rxjs/util/ObjectUnsubscribedError.js
[1] 16.10.27 14:52:48 304 GET /node_modules/rxjs/SubjectSubscription.js
[1] 16.10.27 14:52:48 304 GET /node_modules/rxjs/symbol/rxSubscriber.js
[1] 16.10.27 14:52:48 304 GET /node_modules/rxjs/util/root.js
[1] 16.10.27 14:52:48 304 GET /node_modules/rxjs/util/toSubscriber.js
[1] 16.10.27 14:52:48 304 GET /node_modules/rxjs/symbol/observable.js
[1] 16.10.27 14:52:48 304 GET /node_modules/rxjs/util/isFunction.js
[1] 16.10.27 14:52:48 304 GET /node_modules/rxjs/Observer.js
[1] 16.10.27 14:52:48 304 GET /node_modules/rxjs/util/isArray.js
[1] 16.10.27 14:52:48 304 GET /node_modules/rxjs/util/isObject.js
[1] 16.10.27 14:52:48 304 GET /node_modules/rxjs/util/tryCatch.js
[1] 16.10.27 14:52:48 304 GET /node_modules/rxjs/util/errorObject.js
[1] 16.10.27 14:52:48 304 GET /node_modules/rxjs/util/UnsubscriptionError.js
[1] 16.10.27 14:52:50 404 GET /node_modules/systemjs/dist/main.js.map
[1] 16.10.27 14:52:50 404 GET /node_modules/systemjs/dist/Subject.js.map
[1] 16.10.27 14:52:50 404 GET /node_modules/systemjs/dist/Observable.js.map
[1] 16.10.27 14:52:50 404 GET /node_modules/systemjs/dist/root.js.map
[1] 16.10.27 14:52:50 404 GET /node_modules/systemjs/dist/toSubscriber.js.map
[1] 16.10.27 14:52:50 404 GET /node_modules/systemjs/dist/Subscriber.js.map
[1] 16.10.27 14:52:50 404 GET /node_modules/systemjs/dist/isFunction.js.map
[1] 16.10.27 14:52:50 404 GET /node_modules/systemjs/dist/Subscription.js.map
[1] 16.10.27 14:52:50 404 GET /node_modules/systemjs/dist/isArray.js.map
[1] 16.10.27 14:52:50 404 GET /node_modules/systemjs/dist/isObject.js.map
[1] 16.10.27 14:52:50 404 GET /node_modules/systemjs/dist/tryCatch.js.map
[1] 16.10.27 14:52:50 404 GET /node_modules/systemjs/dist/errorObject.js.map
[1] 16.10.27 14:52:50 404 GET /node_modules/systemjs/dist/UnsubscriptionError.js.map
[1] 16.10.27 14:52:50 404 GET /node_modules/systemjs/dist/Observer.js.map
[1] 16.10.27 14:52:50 404 GET /node_modules/systemjs/dist/rxSubscriber.js.map
[1] 16.10.27 14:52:50 404 GET /node_modules/systemjs/dist/observable.js.map
[1] 16.10.27 14:52:50 404 GET /node_modules/systemjs/dist/ObjectUnsubscribedError.js.map
[1] 16.10.27 14:52:51 404 GET /node_modules/systemjs/dist/SubjectSubscription.js.map
[1] 16.10.27 14:52:51 404 GET /node_modules/systemjs/dist/app.module.js.map
[1] 16.10.27 14:52:51 404 GET /node_modules/systemjs/dist/app.component.js.map
[1] 16.10.27 14:52:52 304 GET /app/app.component.html
```

How can I fix this? What are those .map files anyway? Running `npm install` won't install anything more.

Comment: It's not a fatal error. map are only use to debug. look here if you want that tsc genere map file for your sources [doc typescript compiler](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html)

Comment: The map files are generated, but in a different location.  systemjs seems to think the map file for /app/main.ts is /node_modules/systemjs/dist/main.js.map, when it's /app/main.js.map